# Impedance of L+(C||(C+R))

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, math

[image: Impedance]

Hello fellow human beings,

I am really bad at transposing equasions.
In the picture you can see a simple circuit, of whom I need the equasion in the form: 'Z = Re + jIm'.
I know how to get to the equasion, as you can see in the image, but I have no idea how to get it into the form of 'Z = R + j( w;C;L )'.

Thank you for letting me know, how you would start solving.

Comment: I suggest doing the math in polar form first, and then convert back to rectangular at the end. That way the "jX"s can be treated as + and - angles for L and C, respectively, and added/subtracted to get your final angle (which determines whether it is R+jX or R-jX)

Comment: Using your notation, write the fractional bit as \$\frac{C\times C + CR}{2C+R}\$; substitute \$C \rightarrow \frac{1}{j \omega c}\$; multiply top and bottom by \$(j\omega c \times j\omega c)\$; rationalise; add to \$j\omega L\$